# How do I get the results of one api and use it to make a query in another API using retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to access data in an API by getting the result of an id number in one and querying it into the API I need the data from using retrofit.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should call second api when you get successful result from first api